# No puedo seleccionar varias opciones con un select multiple

Tags: php, html, select

Tengo un problema con un select multiple. Cuando intento seleccionar varias opciones, no puedo y no encuentro el problema.

```html
<div class="input-group">
   <label for="phone">¿Ha introducido cambios en sus hábitos o en su dieta? Marque cuáles…</label>
   <br>
   <select name="cambios[]" multiple>
      <option value="Dejar de fumar">Dejar de fumar</option>
      <option value="Protegerme de la luz" selected>Protegerme de la luz</option>
      <option value="Priorizar cierto tipo de alimentos">Priorizar cierto tipo de alimentos</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: El código HTML parece estar bien, lo he usado y permite seleccionar múltiples opciones.

Comment: Encontre la manera de hacerlo pero hay que pulsar a la vez ctrl. No hay alguna manera de que esto no sea asi?

Comment: No, la selección múltiple del elemento HTML requiere de pulsar un botón (*CTRL* en Windows y *command* en MacOS). La alternativa es utilizar alguna librería de Javascript.

Comment: _No es un bug, es un feature_ ;) Nativamente, es así como funciona (de hecho, si probás en un explorador de archivos, vas a notar el mismo comportamiento: un clic para seleccionar un elemento, Ctrl + clic para seleccionar _de a uno_, y Shift + clic para seleccionar _rangos_ de elementos). Es más, esto se describe [en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#selecting_multiple_options).

Answer (score 0):

No hay ningún problema. Ese es el funcionamiento esperado.

Debes mantener <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> o <kbd>Command</kbd> según el sistema operativo para seleccionar múltiples opciones con el mouse.

En teléfonos, al menos en Chrome de Android, los botones circulares se cambian por checkboxes permitiendo elegir más de uno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más información en la [documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#selecting_multiple_options).